# CiviCRM Receipt Text for Offline Join and Renew

Tags: civimember, receipts

Can someone please explain where the text for the two fields is coming from? receipt_text_signup and receipt_text_renewal

CiviCRM 4.7.x on Drupal 7.

```
{if $formValues.receipt_text_signup}
     <p>{$formValues.receipt_text_signup|htmlize}</p>
    {elseif $formValues.receipt_text_renewal}
     <p>{$formValues.receipt_text_renewal|htmlize}</p>
    {else}
     <p>{ts}Thank you for your membership.{/ts}</p>
```